# How to execute a bash script in Jelly?

Tags: java, bash, maven, jelly

I would like to execute a bash script in `postGoal` section of my maven.xml using Jelly. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. You have to use `jelly:ant` (I mapped it is as `a`). Then just write:

```
<a:exec executable="/bin/bash">
    <a:arg value="script_path"/>
    <a:arg value="srcipt_args"/>
</a:exec>
```